# How to NOT show link title, if link title is left empty

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

Using the link module I have one link field with the setting "Link Title > Optional Title". This allows users to enter a link url without entering a title.

The problem is, the (empty) title is replaced with $item['display_url'] which is redundant since it's followed by the linked url. To clearify my question here's two examples – and what I would actually want instead:

1. If the title is set to "homepage" and url is set to "www.example.com"
   the result is `homepage: www.example.com` (url is linked)
2. If the title is left empty and url is set to "www.example.com"
   the result is `http://www.example.com/: www.example.com` (url is linked)
3. What I want (instead of 2.)
   If the title is left empty and url is set to "www.example.com"
   the result should be `www.example.com` (url is linked)

I have actually found the piece of code that does the replacement – and commented it out. Since this is of course not good practice I would be very happy if anybody could point me to a direction, how to properly override or patch this behaviour.

PS: this is the actual code I commented out in link.module line 527:

```
  $item['title'] = empty($title) ? $item['display_url'] : $title;
```